# From string "AA1-AA5" obtain a vector ("AA1","AA2","AA3","AA4","AA5" ) in R

Tags: r, string, range

An input is a string describing, for example, a range of seats in cinema where rows are named by double letters.

As the output, I would like to see a vector containing ALL individual seats.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `AA` dynamic or not? Can it be a different value?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It goes AA#-ZZ#.

Comment: @mtoto I tried to use regular expressions to detect the elements. Lost on the way. 
By sprintf("AA%d", 1:5) you can generate a series of AA1, ..., AA5;  No idea how to reverse it.

Comment: @Yuri can you explicit what's wrong with my answer ? and provide your MWE

Comment: How many seats per row are there? For example, if you have AA1-BB5, what's the expected output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
I mislead you a little bit. The range for a  row is from AA to ZZ but in the range letters are same:
AA-AA TRUE
ZZ-ZZ TRUE
AA-BB FALSE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
# create a MWE:
v <- "AA1-AA5"
name <- unlist(strsplit(v, '-'))

# get numbers only
ind <- as.numeric(gsub(x = name, pattern = "[[:alpha:]]", replacement = ""))

# create new vector
names <- paste0("AA", ind[1]:ind[2])
```

Comment: there are. The first line recreates your example

Comment: Just replace the first line with: v<-"AA1-AA5"
name<-unlist(strsplit(v, '-'))

Comment: @BrianO'Donnell 
 I tried this, but you way looks simpler. 
 
 test <- "A1-A2"
 row_letter <- unlist(str_extract_all(pattern = "[A-Z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}", test))
 row_letter

Comment: or just `str_extract(pattern="^[[:alpha:]]{2}",test)`

Comment: @Ben - that doesn't work: test<-"AA1-AA2"; library(stringr); str_extract(pattern="^[[:alpha:]]{2}",test) gives "AA"

Comment: OK, I've lost track of what we're trying to do here.  Sorry.